# NoSQL and AppFabric with Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, nosql, appfabric

I have an ASP.net application that I'm moving to Azure. In the application, there's a query that joins 9 tables to produce a user record. Each record is then serialized in json and sent back and forth with the client. To increase query performance, the first time the 9 queries run and the record is serialized in json, the resulting string is saved to a table called JsonUserCache. The table only has 2 columns: JsonUserRecordID (that's unique) and JsonRecord. Each time a user record is requested from the client, the JsonUserCache table is queried first to avoid having to do the query with the 9 joins. When the user logs off, the records he created in the JsonUserCache are deleted.

The table JsonUserCache is SQL Server. I could simply leave everything as is but I'm wondering if there's a better way. I'm thinking about creating a simple dictionary that'll store the key/values and put that dictionary in AppFabric. I'm also considering using a NoSQL provider and if there's an option for Azure or if I should just stick to a dictionary in AppFabric. Or, is there another alternative?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are referring to with the term AppFabric? Do you mean the Caching Service? or something else?

Comment: I mean storing the dictionary in AppFabric. I read that AppFabric is RAM storage so I thought might be faster than SQL Azure or Table storage since these two rely on hard drive IO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "There are only two hard problems in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things."

*Phil Karlton*

You are clearly talking about a cache and as a general principle, you should not persist any cached data (in SQL or anywhere else) as you have the problem of expiring the cache and having to do the deletes (as you currently are). If you insist on storing your result somewhere and don't mind the clearing up afterwards, then look at putting it in an Azure blob - this is easily accessible from the browser and doesn't require that the request be handled by your own application.

To implement it as a traditional cache, look at these options.

1. Use out of the box ASP.NET caching, where you cache in memory on the web role. This means that your join will be re-run on every instance that the user goes to, but depending on the number of instances and the duration of the average session may be the simplest to implement.
2. Use AppFabric Cache. This is an extra API to learn and has additional costs which may get quite high if you have lots of unique visitors.
3. Use a specialised distributed cache such as Memcached. This has the added cost/hassle of having to run it all yourself, but gives you lots of flexibility in the long run.

Edit: All are RAM based. Using ASP.NET caching is simpler to implement and is faster to retrieve the data from cache because it is on the same machine - BUT requires the cache to be populated for each instance of the web role (i.e. it is not distributed). AppFabric caching is distributed but is also a bit slower (network latency) and, depending what you mean by scalable, AppFabric caching currently behaves a bit erratically at scale - so make sure you run tests. If you want scalable, feature rich distributed caching, and it is a big part of your application, go and put in Memcached.

Comment: Which of these options is going to work from RAM? I think AppFabric does this; ASP.net caching too? I should have mentioned that I plan to run the app in multiple instances, with the asp.net engine running along a wcf service; there will be a worker role coming along too later. What's the difference between using ASP.net cache vs AppFabric. Note, I'm not concerned about cost, just scalability and performance. It looks like blobs won't work: the json strings are user sensitive data transferred via HTTPS.